# ffmpeg working on command line only, not with php

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg https://github.com/olaferlandsen/ffmpeg-php-class. But when i am running code it is not working. Please help me to solve this issue if anyone know. Below is the code

```
$FFmpeg = new FFmpeg( "/etc/bin/ffmpeg" );
$FFmpeg->input( '/opt/lampp/htdocs/ffmpeg/1.wav' )->output( '/opt/lampp/htdocs/ffmpeg/ss.mp3' );
$FFmpeg->ready();
```

Comment: any error you are getting :-

Comment: The path to the binary is wrong, whats `whereis ffmpeg` show `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`?

Comment: using /usr/bin/ffmpeg, stll not working

Comment: No error showing

Comment: Gettin this error /usr/bin/ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libdirac_encoder.so.0) /usr/bin/ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libdirac_encoder.so.0) /usr/bin/ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libdirac_decoder.so.0) /usr/bin/ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libdirac_decoder.so.0)

Comment: when i am using this echo shell_exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y  -i "/opt/lampp/htdocs/ffmpeg/1.wav" /opt/lampp/htdocs/ffmpeg/ses.mp3 2<&1');

Answer (score 0):

use without cunstructor:-

```
        $FFmpeg = new FFmpeg();
        $FFmpeg->input( '/opt/lampp/htdocs/ffmpeg/1.wav' )->output( '/opt/lampp/htdocs/ffmpeg/ss.mp3' );
        $FFmpeg->ready();
```